# Next and Strapi mySQL url on root

Tags: mysql, next.js, strapi

In this tutorial example is with a postgre database.
https://strapi.io/blog/user-authentication-in-next-js-with-strapi

I install strapi and next on my local computer and I try to find mySQL url.
I search on doc and other things but I didn't find anything. I use Xampp

My access is http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/index.php?route=/database/structure&db=iloveshare

I don't have any password and user is root
I need this for my .env

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=http://localhost:1337
NEXT_PUBLIC_DATABASE_URL=HERE <========
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

It’s http://localhost:8080

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=http://localhost:1337
NEXT_PUBLIC_DATABASE_URL=http://localhost:8080
DB_USER=root
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
```